# Traversing word-by-word in VBA through the contents of a Word textbox

Tags: vba, textbox, formatting, ms-word

Given a Microsoft Word textbox filled with formatted text, how do I use VBA to:

1. Iterate through the textbox content, word-by-word
2. At each iteration, copy/cut out that one word (including its formatting) out of the text box
3. Append (i.e. paste) that cut formatted word into the end of a second Microsoft Word textbox

*[My situation is as follows: I have multiple continuous related texts (i.e. text + footnotes + a second set of footnotes, etc.), and my goal is to programatically lay all of that out in Word text boxes on pages of a Microsoft Word document.*

*I will set up the second box (that one that the words are being pasted into) to be auto-sizing, and I will then stop the "cut-paste" process once the second box gets to a certain size (which will be programatically determined based on page margins, other textboxes already occupying the page, etc.).]*

I'm breaking my head over this for weeks with no results! Thanks a LOT to anyone who can send me in the right direction...

Comment: In short, I've tried other trial-and-error (i.e. binary search) strategies that instead of cutting and pasting involve resizing exisitng textboxes, but those methods proved to be WAY too slow.

I'd like to try what I'm describing above, but I do not know how to do these 3 steps: 1) iterate through the words of a textbox, 2) cut out the word out of the textbox, 3) append it to a different textbox.